# Does youtube allow modify its images or use youtube iframes without any account?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I created some youtube video share system but I am not sure some cases.I am just grap youtube id and push it to iframe (does youtube allow it?),and when a lot of posts loaded I use images and I modify youtube image like this:

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'+youtube_id+'/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=-dIjbVQ4v9JY3UAEGZBDGDUK9Fc
```

I want to know that is it allowed?

Answer (score 0):

## Modify its images

Under [*Terms of Service*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms)

> II. Prohibitions
>
> - modify or replace the text, images, or other content of the YouTube search results, including (i) changing the order in which search results are presented as YouTube search results, or (ii) intermixing sources other than YouTube when search results are presented as YouTube search results;

---

## Use iframes without any account

It is possible under [Requirements](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements)

> Requirements
>
> The user's browser must support the HTML5 **`postMessage`** feature. Most modern browsers support **`postMessage`**, though Internet Explorer 7 does not support it.
>
> Embedded players must have a viewport that is at least 200px by 200px. If the player displays controls, it must be large enough to fully display the controls without shrinking the viewport below the minimum size. We recommend 16:9 players be at least 480 pixels wide and 270 pixels tall.
>
> Any web page that uses the IFrame API must also implement the following JavaScript function:
>
> - **`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`** – The API will call this function when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API, which enables you to then use the API on your page. Thus, this function might create the player objects that you want to display when the page loads.

Here is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
// after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '390',
width: '640',
videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady,
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
}
});
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
// The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
// the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
done = true;
}
}
function stopVideo() {
player.stopVideo();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you this was really useful but I have done this with another way but I am not sure it is allowed:when someone pasted youtube url ,I get youtube id and  then I append iframe relative to this youtube id like below:
'<iframe class="" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+src+'?autoplay=0></iframe>'
is It allowed?just append iframe?Also picture like this:<img  class="share-iframe" width="95%" height="380" \
    src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'+youtube_id+'/hqdefault.jpg" />